# Java garbage collection when there is no referencing object

Tags: java, garbage-collection

For example with the following code,

```
class Dog {
    Dog parent;
    Dog (Dog parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    Dog makeDog (Dog dog) {
        return new Dog(new Dog(new Dog(dog)));
    }
}

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dog dog = new Dog(null);
        dog = dog.makeDog(dog);
        Dog anotherDog = new Dog(dog);
        /*
         * many lines of code
         */
        if (anotherDog.parent.parent.parent.parent.parent == null) {
            System.out.println("null");
        }
    }
}
```

Is this program guaranteed to print null?

Most of my programs are in C, and this is the way I build linked lists, trees, graphs et cetera. But I am really not sure how the Java garbage collector will deal with such code, so in the real program, I chose to store the references elsewhere so the GC can know that the objects are indeed not garbage.

Any helps are welcome.

Comment: Why would the GC think they're garbage? Every dog is reachable from a chain of references from the variable anotherDog in the stack of the main thread.

Comment: what if I add `dog = null`?

Comment: Every dog would still be reachable from a chain of references from the variable anotherDog in the stack of the main thread.

Comment: In java you have built in data structures and I suggest you use those where possible. E.g. It has lists, sets, hash maps, trees, queues and deques.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as an object is reachable through a chain of strong references from a GC root (a thread stack, or a static variable), it will not be garbage collected. It doesn't matter how convoluted the path to the object is.

Comment: That's incorrect. `Foo foo = new Foo(); Bar bar = new Bar(); bar.setFoo(foo); foo.setBar(bar); foo = null; bar = null;` Do you really think bar and foo are not eligible to GC? Yet both bar and foo still have a reference to them.

Comment: I think you need to add "a strong reference path from the GC root".

Comment: @JBNizet In your example, would you say that *you* have any reference to foo or bar? That's how I understood it, though it could be stated more clearly.

Comment: @maaartinus: agreed. The answer is correct or incorrect depending on the definition of *you*. I read it as "there is a reference". You read it as "the method had a reference". I think we can agree that the answer could be clearer.